# What is the scope of std::mutex object?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is the sample code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

int value = 0;

void criticalSection(int changeValue)
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniqueLock(mtx);
    value = changeValue;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    uniqueLock.unlock();
    uniqueLock.lock();
    ++value;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::thread t1(criticalSection, 1), t2(criticalSection, 2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is: what is the scope of mtx in the above code? Will each thread create a mtx within that thread? Is there any difference if I specify mtx as a global variable instead of a local variable?

I just started to learn multithread in C++. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Having function `void foo () {int bar = 0; }`, what is the scope of `bar` variable, and will new `bar` variable be created upon each invocation of `foo` function? The answer is the same with `std::mutex`.

Comment: The scope of a `std::mutex` is the same as for any other object. "_Will each thread create a mtx within that thread?_"  - Yes, unless you make it `static` [example](https://godbolt.org/z/h83oY6Ej7)

Comment: It's the same scope as if `int a;` was declared instead of it.

Comment: Rule is simple: scope of mutex must match scope of protected data.

Comment: Thank you all very much. This is my first time asking a question and I got so many helpful replies. I hope you all have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special scoping rules for mutexes. Their scope ends on the next `}`. In your code every call to `criticalSection` creates a new `mutex` instance. Hence, the mutex cannot possibly be used to synchronize the two threads. To do so, both threads would need to use the same mutex.

You can pass a reference to a mutex to the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

int value = 0;

void criticalSection(int changeValue,std::mutex& mtx)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> uniqueLock(mtx);
    //...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::thread t1(criticalSection, 1,std::ref(mtx)), t2(criticalSection, 2,std::ref(mtx));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively you could use a `std::atomic<int> value;` and drop the mutex when `value` is the only shared state.

Comment: Thank you. After reading your answer my question is solved. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The `mutex` type doesn't change C++ rules on how variables and objects work.

If you declare a non-`static` variable on the stack, each call to that function will create its own version of that variable. Regardless of which thread it is. These are all separate and distinct objects.

When you lock a `mutex`, you are locking *that object*. Other objects of the same type are unrelated to that lock.

To make a `mutex` useful, both of the pieces of code trying to lock it must be locking the *same object*. How you accomplish this is ultimately up to your needs.

Comment: Well, it's a little magical, just not in any way relevant to scope

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I know I need to make the mutex object static.